# Вывод картинки в пост django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь вывести картинку в свой блог, но вместо этого получаю ошибку:

> OperationalError at /admin/blog/post/.

В setting.py прописал:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

в models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media', blank=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

в urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
   url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
   url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
   url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
   url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',
   {'document_root':'media'}),
   ]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

и вывожу вот так:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
 <body class="w3-light-grey">
  {% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
      <h3><b><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}
      </a></b></h3>
      <span class="w3-opacity">{{ post.published_date }}</span>    
      <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
      <img src="{{ post.image.url }}">  
    {% endfor %}  
  {% endblock content %}
```

файл views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def post_list(request):  
posts =
```

Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = PostForm()
return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})   

def post_edit(request, pk):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
   if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.published_date = timezone.now()
        post.save()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = PostForm(instance=post)
return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

покажите views.py

Сейчас Ваша картинка загружается в /media/static/media/

странная строка как по мне -> author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

вместо {% endblock content %}  попробуйте поставить просто {% endblock %}

Comment: ,1.  в models.py исправил - image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank=True) - ошибка все равно не исчезла.
2. дополнил вопрос файлом views.py

Comment: это потому что Вы передаете в шаблон post, а картинку пытаетесь взять с {}for post in posts} исправьте на {% for post in post%}, должно заработать